# leaflet 0.6.4 on firefox android freeze functionality

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, mobile, leaflet

I switch from leaflet 0.5 to 0.6.4 to be able to use the 'overlayremove' event.

However since that, on firefox android I having a lot a problems:

1. I can't change baselayer.
2. Overlays checkbox aren't taken into account.
3. When I'm slide on the map when the leafelt layer management form is open, it won't close like it use to...

BTW: point 3. is true on chrome for android as well.

Answer (score 0):

Point 3 you can fix adding code below (tested on Chrome Android):

```
map.on('move', function(e) {
  $('.leaflet-control-layers').removeClass('leaflet-control-layers-expanded');
});
```

You can change `move` to `moveend` to close layers' box when you stop moving.